# Choices field to be depend on the count() of current class

Tags: django, model

I want to add a choices field to a class that is filled with numbers. The number of numbers must be the total count of the Object.objects.count().

I thought to make it like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):

    quantity = Category.objects.count() + 1
    PRIORITY = tuple((str(n), str(n)) for n in range(aantal + 1))
```

But then I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'Category' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to provide those choices in a form, so your best bet would be to use an IntegerField and then read http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/ and make your form according to that and change the choices for that field in **init**() (as shown [here](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/26/))

Comment: Thanks that helped alot! :) Another small question: How to check if a field has a value on the __init__ on the forms.ModelForm. Like: self.fields['language'] <<< How to check if this has a value

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the `name error` you should create a dedicated method to your model for counting your categories:

```
def total_categories(self):
    return Category.objects.count()
```